# How to refactor this code with if statement

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have code with if statement (below). Is it possible to refactor this code? because in this method is ugly if statement :(

```
  getOverallAmount(estimate) {
    const {installments} = estimate;
    const {vipValue} = estimate;
    if (installments !== 1) {
      const oneInstallment = vipValue / installments;
      const allWithOneInst = vipValue - (oneInstallment * installments) + 1;
      return oneInstallment + allWithOneInst;
    }
    return vipValue;
  }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `+1`, is it really necessary for the algorithm?

Comment: Why do i get cons? is not a possible refactoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of the `if` statement:

```
getOverallAmount(estimate) {
  const {installments} = estimate;
  const {vipValue} = estimate;
  const oneInstallment = vipValue / installments;
  const allWithOneInst = vipValue - (oneInstallment * installments) + 1;
  
  return (installments !== 1) ? oneInstallment + allWithOneInst : vipValue;
}
```